# How to redirect all ipv6 dns request to local dnsmasq when there isn’t a nat table on my router?

Tags: iptables

I have redirected all ipv4 dns request to my local dns server on port 60053 use iptables `-J redirect`.

But when I trying to do the same things for ipv6 dns request I failed, cause there isn’t a nat table for ipv6 on my router.

I have googled but didn’t found a solution, any suggestions would be appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `nat` table isn't there because the kernel module isn't loaded. You'll need to load it (and probably install it first). If you're on OpenWRT, the package you need is `ip6tables-mod-nat`.

Comment: I use a asus router running Merlin, I googled and found https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/issues/225 maybe I can use entware to upgrade iptables to support ipv6 nat table. I’ll try later, thanks.